# To divide string of characters with Lua

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

My string looks like this: `nxs_dev_flo.nexus` and I want to return only `nxs_dev_flo`

Here is what I tried:

```
location /luatest {
   default_type 'text/plain';
   content_by_lua 'ngx.say(split(ngx.var.host, "."))';
}
```

I get a 500 error with this in log:

> 2018/02/06 17:59:52 [error] 7237#7237: *87 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(default:55):1: attempt to call global 'split' (a nil value)
>   stack traceback:
>   coroutine 0:
>       content_by_lua(default:55): in function , client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /luatest HTTP/1.1", host: "nxs_flo_dev.nexus"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` is not a standard Lua function and apparently not one provided by nginx.

Try `ngx.say(ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%."))` instead.

[string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match) is a standard Lua function.

Comment: Do you have a link that explains me how the function works `:match()` ?Because I can not find it on the internet ..

Comment: [Programming In Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) is your friend for pattern information, and the [Lua Users Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) has more.